# Upgrade older SQL 2008 to 2008 R2 on active/passive cluster

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an active/Passive SQL Server 2008 cluster in production that I need to upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2. I just want to make sure I understand all the steps before starting this in production.

1. Run the SQL installer on the passive node and get through the setup files. Exit the installer and reboot. fail the cluster to the passive node.
2. Run the installer on the active node and update the shared components and SQL Setup files. Exit the installer and reboot. Fail the cluster back.
3. Run the installer on the passive node and select the Upgrade option.
4. Reboot and patch (service pack, etc) until no new patches are available on the passive node.
5. Fail the cluster to the passive node.
6. Upgrade and patch the original active node.
7. Fail the cluster back to the original Active node.

Did I miss anything? Are there any major issues I should be aware of?

I am only running the SQL instance and full text search. SSAS and SSRS are not installed.

I am using this KB as my guide - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191295.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be that complex.

On the passive node upgrade the instance to SQL 2008 R2.  Then reboot that node.  Then failover.  At this point the database will be upgraded to SQL 2008 R2.

On the now passive node upgrade the instance to SQL 2008 R2.

There's an article I wrote about upgrading a [SQL 2005 cluster to SQL 2008](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/clustering/upgrading-a-sql-server-2005-cluster-to-a-sql-server-2008).  It's basically the same process.